# Django Group by month and display in template by month

Tags: django, distinct, group

```
`class Daily(models.Model):
    transid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    transdate = models.DateField()
    transdetails = models.ForeignKey(Details, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transcategory = models.ForeignKey(MasterCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transmode = models.ForeignKey(PaymentMode, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transsubdetails = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    transamount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s" % (
            self.transid,
            self.transdate,
            self.transdetails,
            self.transcategory,
            self.transmode,
            self.transsubdetails,
            self.transamount)`
```

Above is my model
And my template is as below

```
{% for month in months %}
<h3>{{ month__month }}</h3>
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Details</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Pay Mode</th>
    <th>Sub Details</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </tr>
{% for trans in mydata %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ trans.transid }}</td>
        <td>{{ trans.transdate }}</td>
        <td>{{ trans.transdetails }}</td>
        <td>{{ trans.transcategory }}</td>
        <td>{{ trans.transmode }}</td>
        <td>{{ trans.transsubdetails }}</td>
        <td>{{ trans.transamount }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

and my view is

```
def alltrans(request):
    my_data = Daily.objects.all()
    mnths = len(Daily.objects.values('transdate__month').distinct())+1
    totamount = Daily.objects.all().aggregate(totb=Sum('transamount'))['totb']
    mnths1 = Daily.objects.values('transdate__month').distinct(),
    monthsba = [Daily.objects.filter(transdate__month=month) for month in range(1, mnths)]
    ms = {
        'months': mnths1,
        'monthsbal': monthsba,
        'mydata': my_data,
        'totamount': totamount,
        'title': 'All Trans',
    }
    return render(request, 'alltrans.html', ms)
```

I am trying to bring in template by month ...

January sum(transamount) filter by month = 1 id Date Details Category Pay Mode Sub Details Amount

February sum(transamount) filter by month = 2

and so on

Please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to build the data manually as you are trying. By selecting the months (just as you did) and then looping through the data filtering by it, while aggregating values:

views.py

```py
def trans_per_month(request):
    months = Daily.objects.values('transdate__month').distinct()
    data = {}
    for obj in months:
        month = calendar.month_name[obj['transdate__month']]
        qs = (
            Daily.objects
            .filter(transdate__month=obj['transdate__month'])
        )
        amount = qs.aggregate(total=Sum('transamount'))

        data[obj['transdate__month']] = {
            'month': month,
            'qs': qs,
            'total': amount['total']
        }

    context = {'data': data}

    return render(request, 'trans_per_month.html', context)
```

trans_per_month.html

```
<body>
    {% for key, value in data.items %}
    <h3>{{ value.month }}</h3>
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Details</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Pay Mode</th>
            <th>Sub Details</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>

        {% for obj in value.qs %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ obj.transid }}</td>
            <td>{{ obj.transdate }}</td>
            <td>{{ obj.transdetails }}</td>
            <td>{{ obj.transcategory }}</td>
            <td>{{ obj.transmode }}</td>
            <td>{{ obj.transsubdetails }}</td>
            <td>{{ obj.transamount }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">Total</td>
            <td>{{ value.total }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

Comment: Like a page break report. I want all my transactions filtered by month of transdate. report title should be the name of the month if 1 January then all my trans for month 1 and total of my trans for month 1
same vise all the datas which has the months in database only should display
If the data has only first 3 months, then it should display the three month details
as page break

Comment: I do not want to sound impolite. But, you should be more specific about what you want from the beginning. What you are asking has several deviations from your original question. Although, I will try to help as soon as I have the time.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Now it is up to you to tweak the query to your needs :)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear at the first time.
Thanks for the updated answer, I will try to execute.